# About calculation of extrinsic curvature

Tags: curvature, general-relativity

I'm very primary in the field of GR(General relativity). I read a lot of references about extrinsic and intrinsic curvature, but none of them refers to how to compute an extrinsic curvature for a given metric. Does any one know how to compute extrinsic curvature for a given metric such as ADS?

Comment: A metric only knows about intrinsic curvature, you need an embedding higher dimensional space to talk about extrinsic curvature. Imagine a cylinder: the metric is identical to a metric of a plane, but the extrinsic curvature is nonzero.

Comment: Perhaps you mean the extrinsic curvature of the hypersurfaces $x^0=\textrm{const}$ in a given coordinate system. In this specific case, $K_{ik}=-N\Gamma^0_{ik}$ as given in MTW $\S21.5$. $N$ is the lapse (from lapse-shift formalism), and $\Gamma$ the Christoffel symbols in the given coordinate system.